# DAX parallelperiod until today

Tags: report, reporting, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a YTD DAX statement that gives me the parallel period from last year until a specific date.
Currently I have :

```
    SumQty = SUM('Order Table'[Quantity])
```

```
    YTD LY = CALCULATE([SumQty];PARALLELPERIOD('DIM Dates'[Date];-12;MONTH))
```

But this calculates me values for the whole last year instead of from January till August(now)
So in the end i need a Table which shows me the Qunatity of every month compared to the quantity last year in the same time period.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the table you specified, you need to create 2 YTD measures:

```
Current YTD = CALCULATE ( [SumQty]; DATESYTD ( 'DIM Dates'[Date] ) )
```

```
PY YTD = CALCULATE ( [SumQty]; DATEADD ( DATESYTD ( 'DIM Dates'[Date] ); -1; YEAR ) )
```

Then use a matrix visualization and put measures [Current YTD] and [PY YTD] under Values section and 'DIM Dates'[Year] and 'DIM Dates'[Month] (I suppose you have them in your DIM Dates table) under Lines section.

That would give you the following table:

[image]

Please remember to have your 'DIM Dates' relationship to the 'Order Table' correctly configured in order to have your time intelligence calculations done right. You can find more info [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/time-intelligence-in-power-bi-desktop/).